# "Linking to another page" is over simplifying my question

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm building my website out from a template. It has an element named 'portfolio-filters.' It's on my blog page and looks like this:

[portfolio-filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3NpV.png)

With this, when a visitor clicks one of the buttons, all the corresponding content/posts appear underneath. If they click another button, those content/posts appear, and so on. When the 'Show All' button is click everything appears below.

On my home page I have four links:
Travel
Fashion
Lifestyle
Motivation

How do I code the links on the home page so that, for example, the person clicks the 'travel' button it will take them to the blog page with the 'travel' button highlighted and all the travel content/posts appearing below?

The typical code on my home page:
*on*travel (Link is inside a DIV Class)

The code of the portfolio-filters on the blog page:

```
<section class="small-gap filter-blog">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="portfolio-filters">
              <ul>
                <li class="active" data-filter="*"><span>Show All</span></li>
                <li data-filter=".travel"><span>travel</span></li>
                <li data-filter=".fashion"><span>fashion</span></li>
                <li data-filter=".lifestyle"><span>lifestyle</span></li>
                <li data-filter=".Motivation"><span>Motivation</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Is this possible?

Thank You
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your pages are html and has this code on it, you can remove the class `active` on the `Show All` button and add it to the correct one you want to be highlighted.

did I understand your question correct?

Comment: My Home Page has 4 hyperlinks: "Fashion", "Travel", "Lifestyle", "Motivation." They are straight forwards links all going to my blog page. The home page is where I need to know how to link to the blog page. On the blog page, there is an element with the same buttons, however, if you click, for example, the "Travel" button all the content pertaining to "Travel" will appear on the page with the "Travel" button activated.

Comment: continued ... If you then click the Fashion button, all the "Travel" content is replaced by the "Fashion" content and the "Fashion" button is active. What I want to do is be able to, from the 'Home Page" click the "Travel" button, and it's hyperlinked to the blog page with the "Travel" button active and all its content visible. If the person instead clicked the "Fashion" link on the "Home Page" it would take them to the same blog page but with the "Fashion" link active and all the fashion content visable.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the first part of your question on how you link pages.
First you will need what is know as an "anchor tag" done with the "a" letter.

Next you will need an "href", and it is best to add a "class" to this.

```
<a class="link" href="https://www.url.com></a>
```

Then whatever text you put between the`"<a></a>"` anchor tags is what will appear on your website. 
of example:

```
<a class="link" href="https://www.travel-url.com>Travel Website</a>
```